# angular orderBy in ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Cant find any existing questions that match my problem...

OrderBy isn't working for me; I've boiled down to the following example code:

controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularSampleApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.products = [{
        product_summary: {
            purchase_id: 225,
            purchase_date: '2014-09-05T08:58:59+10:00',
            title: 'Product 1',
        }
    }, {
        product_summary: {
            purchase_id: 226,
            purchase_date: '2014-09-05T11:34:28+10:00',
            title: 'Product 2',
        }
    }];

    $scope.purchaseDate = function(product) {
      return Date.parse(product.product_summary.purchase_date);
    }

});
```

and view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:purchaseDate">
  {{product.product_summary.title}} : {{product.product_summary.purchase_date}}
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:purchaseDate:reverse">
  {{product.product_summary.title}} : {{product.product_summary.purchase_date}}
</ul>
```

Both lists are in the same order.

As far as I can see, I'm doing things properly - the purchaseDate function returns the Date.parse output which is an int, so as far as I can see, this should work...

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reverse
>   (optional)
>   boolean 
>   Reverse the order of the array.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

`reverse` is a variable, it needs to be set to either true or false.  If you use an undefined variable, it is "falsy", so it behaves as if you hadn't told it to reverse.  Add `$scope.reverse = true` and it will work.

Edit:  Actually, you probably need to do:

```
orderBy:'productSummary.purchaseDate':reverse
```

as well to order it by purchaseDate

Comment: thanks! just worked out the same thing myself! It terms of purchaseDate - I created a function to parse the Date and return the epoch. I'll check now to see if product_summary.purchase_date works as well.

Comment: turns out it can't sort on a string date in ISO86012 format. So left in the function to convert to epoch.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've just realised that the second parameter to the orderBy isn't 'reverse', it's true to reverse, false not to reverse.

Should have read the docs properly....